# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll'

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, expression-encoder

I get this error message when I try to access my localhost website. When I built the project all dependencies was successfully solved, after that i deployed the application on IIS (I'm using an custom application pool which supports 32-bit applications), and when I try to access it from localhost:8080 I get this error. I also installed Microsoft Expression 4 tool.
This is my stack trace:

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The specified module could not be found.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The specified module could not be found.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The specified module could not be found.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930508 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254